# Add mutliple nested user input keys in a json file python

Tags: python, json

I stuck with a problem here. I'm need to save user input in a json file.At start the file will look like this

```
{
    "groups": [
    ]
}
```

After the processing, it should look like this

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "group-10": {
            "hosts": [{
                "192.168.1.1": {
                    "user": "user1",
                    "passwd": "password2"
                },
                "192.168.10.1": {
                    "user": "user10",
                    "passwd": "password10"
                }
            }],
            "Objects": [{
                "object1": {
                    "default_in": 10,
                    "default_out": 100,
                    "default_unit": "mbps"
                },
                "object5": {
                    "default_in": 500,
                    "default_out": 700,
                    "default_unit": "kbps"
                }
            }]
        },
        "group-15": {
            "hosts": [{
                "172.1.1.1": {
                    "user": "user0",
                    "passwd": "password2"
                },
                "192.100.1.1": {
                    "user": "user5",
                    "passwd": "password5"
                }
            }],
            "Objects": [{
                "object9": {
                    "default_in": 3000,
                    "default_out": 3000,
                    "default_unit": "mbps"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that hosts and Objects are the only constant here which will be added after user specify the group name/numeber which can be random. Input and output both should be in a json file and code needs to be in python. Kindly help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use json dump to dump the entire object into a JSON file. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Yes. Problem for me here is adding only keys with null values and than replacing that null value with another pair of key/value. Like at the start I only have groups[]. I need to ask group name from the user and save it as groups[{'group-10': ' '}].. Than replace the empty/null value with "hosts"

Comment: That's still do able right? Are you seeing any issue implementing the same?

Comment: Actually I'm very new to python.. so I'm having issue with how to implement the solution. How to add only key to a dict and than replace the value part with another key.. I'm having problem with how to code this.

Comment: Once you have an initial dictionary in place. dict['index'] = value will change the value. Dictionary by default is mutable and will allow for changing the value.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].